# Getting error when sending XML as body instead of JSON

Tags: xml, symfony, serialization, fosrestbundle, symfony4

I'm developing a simple Symfony 4 application with the JMSSerializerBundle and the RestBundle, which saves data from POST requests and returns data for GET requests. The requests mostly uses JSON as format, but I need one POST route with accepts and parse XML.

I've no problems with all the JSON requests, but the XML one gives me the following error:

```
(1/1) ClassNotFoundException

Attempted to load class "XmlEncoder" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

My Configuration for the RestBundle looks like this:

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: false
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    serializer:
        serialize_null: true
```

and the POST method is simply this:

```
/**
* @Post("/test")
*/
public function postAction(Request $request) {
    dump($request); die();
}
```

I set the Content-Type header of the request to `application/xml`. If I cange that to JSON and send an empty body (or one with valid JSON) everything works (I get the dumbed request).

I also tried to add this `use` statement: `use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;`, but that changes nothing.

Where is my error? Why does the JSON works very well, but the XML gives me errors? Thanks for help!

**Edit:** The problem doesn't occur, if i remove the `Content-Type: application/xml`. But I don't know, why this is the problem and I'm not sure, if the user of the API in the future won't send this specific header. What can I do?